# Dart bwu_datagrid error

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, bwu-datagrid

I run this code from [bwu_datagrid example](http://bwu-dart.github.io/bwu_datagrid/example/e01_simple.html) in Dart Editor:

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: 'basicExample'
version: 0.0.1
description: A web app built using polymer.dart.
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  browser: '>=0.10.0 <0.11.0'
  polymer: '>=0.16.0 <0.17.0'
  bwu_datagrid: any
  js: any
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="scaffolded-by" content="https://github.com/google/stagehand">
  <title>basicExample</title>

  <link rel="import" href="packages/basicExample/app_element.html">

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='example.css'>
</head>

<body>

  <h3>Some table</h3>
  <app-element></app-element>

  <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app_element.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel='import' href='../../packages/bwu_datagrid/bwu_datagrid.html'>

<polymer-element name='app-element'>
  <template>
    <!--<link rel='stylesheet' href='packages/bwu_datagrid/asset/grid.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='packages/bwu_datagrid/asset/default_theme.css' > -->
    <!-- link rel='stylesheet' href='../web/example.css' -->

    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }
      table {
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td valign='top' width='50%'>
          <bwu-datagrid id='myGrid' style='width:600px;height:500px;'></bwu-datagrid>
        </td>
        <td valign='top'>
          <h2>Demonstrates:</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>basic grid with minimal configuration</li>
          </ul>
            <h2>View Source:</h2>
            <ul>
              <li><A href='https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid/blob/master/example/src/e01_simple/app_element.dart' target='_sourcewindow'> View the source for this example on Github</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </template>
  <script type='application/dart' src='app_element.dart'></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**app_element.dart**

```
library app_element;

import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

import 'package:bwu_datagrid/datagrid/helpers.dart';
import 'package:bwu_datagrid/bwu_datagrid.dart';

@CustomTag('app-element')
class AppElement extends PolymerElement {
  AppElement.created() : super.created();

  BwuDatagrid grid;
  List<Column> columns = [
    new Column(id: 'title', name: 'Title', field: 'title'),
    new Column(id: 'duration', name: 'Duration', field: 'duration'),
    new Column(id: '%', name: '% Complete', field: 'percentComplete'),
    new Column(id: 'start', name: 'Start', field: 'start'),
    new Column(id: 'finish', name: 'Finish', field: 'finish'),
    new Column(
        id: 'effort-driven', name: 'Effort Driven', field: 'effortDriven')
  ];

  var gridOptions = new GridOptions(enableCellNavigation: true, enableColumnReorder: false);

  @override
  void attached() {
    super.attached();

    try {      

      grid = $['myGrid'];

      var data = new MapDataItemProvider(); //List<Map>(500);
      for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        data.items.add(new MapDataItem({
          'title': 'Task ${i}',
          'duration': '5 days',
          'percentComplete': new math.Random().nextInt(100).round(),
          'start': '01/01/2009',
          'finish': '01/05/2009',
          'effortDriven': (i % 5 == 0)
        }));
      }

      grid.setup(dataProvider: data, columns: columns, gridOptions: gridOptions);
    } on NoSuchMethodError catch (e) {
      print('$e\n\n${e.stackTrace}');
      print ('it is not worked -1-');
    } on RangeError catch (e) {
      print('$e\n\n${e.stackTrace}');
      print ('it is not worked -2-');
    } on TypeError catch (e) {
      print('$e\n\n${e.stackTrace}');
      print ('it is not worked -3-');
    } catch (e) {
      print('$e');
      print ('it is not worked -4-');
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this code in Dart Editor, I get an error:

```
Observatory listening at http://127.0.0.1:59681/
Exception: Uncaught Error: Invalid argument (value): Not a valid class token: ""
Stack Trace:
#0      CssClassSetImpl._validateToken (file:///mnt/data/b/build/slave/dartium-lucid64-full-stable/build/src/dart/sdk/lib/html/html_common/css_class_set.dart:13)
#1      CssClassSetImpl.add (file:///mnt/data/b/build/slave/dartium-lucid64-full-stable/build/src/dart/sdk/lib/html/html_common/css_class_set.dart:108)
#2      BwuDatagrid._createColumnHeaders (package:bwu_datagrid/bwu_datagrid.dart:749:21)
#3      BwuDatagrid._finishInitialization (package:bwu_datagrid/bwu_datagrid.dart:369:7)
#4      BwuDatagrid._init (package:bwu_datagrid/bwu_datagrid.dart:333:7)
#5      BwuDatagrid.setup.<anonymous closure> (package:bwu_datagrid/bwu_datagrid.dart:184:9)
#6      Future.Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:118)
#7      Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:16)
#8      _Timer._Timer.<anonymous closure> (dart:html:42314)
```

Why I get this problem? Thank you.

I use CentOS 7 and Dart 1.10.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem caused by a breaking change in Dart 1.10.
- https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid/pull/108
- https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid/issues/106
I try to get an updated version published ASAP.

Comment: I published a new fixed version.